# Need an example of "br_table" instruction of WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly

I need an example of "br_table" instruction of WebAssembly as I do not know how to use this instruction directly in WebAssembly text format.

Just like the code shows below, I cannot figure out what part it is  corresponding to its constructing structure. Which part is its "default_target" or "target_table" and etc?

`(br_table 0 1 2 (i32.const 16) (get_local 0))`

[image]

Comment: Post more details of your problem. What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is an example of the syntax, the [WebAssembly test suite](https://github.com/WebAssembly/testsuite) is a good reference. The `br_table` spec tests are here:

https://github.com/WebAssembly/testsuite/blob/master/br_table.wast

Here's one example:

```
(br_table 1 1 1 (i32.const 5) (i32.const 1))
```